Trigonometry/Control Systems: Gain and Phase Between Two Chirp Signals
I have the following scenario where I have to analyze the gain and phase relationship between two chirp signals.
Specifically, I generate the first chirp signal exhibiting the form  $$S_1 = A \sin(\omega(t) t)$$ following the frequency profile $$\omega(t) = k(t)$$
and I pass this signal into a Linear Time Invariant (LTI) dynamical system, such as a mass-spring-damper or a RLC circuit, and get the second chirp signal outputted from the system exhibiting the form $$S_2 = B(\omega) \sin(\omega(t) t + \phi(\omega))$$
And I am interested in the gain and phase as a function of the frequency $\omega$, i.e $B(\omega)$ and $\phi(\omega)$
ALL I HAVE is the perfect non-noisy measurement of those two chirp signals in the time-domain, for example as shown below:
Two Chirp Signals
My question is, is it possible to get $B(\omega)$ and $\phi(\omega)$ through trigonometry tricks and fundamental mathematical operations on these time-domain measurements only? I understand one could have a computer algorithm that detects the peaks of S1 and S2 and then gets the gains and phases that way, but that isn't what I want.
ONE FINAL NOTE, since you are generating S1 yourself you should be able to have access to the cosine part of S1, $A \cos(\omega(t) t)$, as well. And you know the value of A obviously. You can also simply set A to 1.

In general, no. If an impulse is fed in and you have the impulse response, you characterize the transfer function of the RLC circuit. Then you can convolve impulse response and S1 to get S2

I know that you are not asking this. But for LTI system, in general, only if a pure sinusoid is input, you get a scaled and phase shifted sinusoid. In your case, we need to know k(t)
